# How to limit the width of my footer

Tags: html, css, footer, responsive

I want the size of my footer in the bottom of the page to be the same as my navigation bar in the top (with some white space in the corners).

The bar is inside a container which has `container{margin:auto;}`thats why there is white space in the corners .

I don't understand why the footer took the whole screen width, it is inside the same container as the bar on top.

here is the footer css:

```
.down{
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;

}
```

[image: Portfolio]

I don't want to edit the margin left and right because it wont be responsive anymore

Comment: You haven't provided width in your css class so it will occupy all the width available

Answer (score 0):

Tough to say without the HTML but try adding the following rule to the container:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
```

The footer has a position absolute on it. By giving the container a relative position, the footer will be positioned relative to the container instead of the body.

This will cause the footer to not be attached to the bottom of the window, but the bottom of the content. So in addition, add a minimum height to the container:

```
.container {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put your `<div class="down">` inside the container

```
<div class="container">
    <nav></nav>
    <div class="down">
    </div>
    </div>


.down{
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: is it inside the container

Comment: yes, if you put it inside the container then it's working fine otherwise it will contain full width of the screen.

Comment: thanks bro . this is the correct answer should be marked as green